# Other ways to say "What's happening?"

Tags: idioms, american-english, british-english, synonyms, slang

Can you suggest similar expressions to "What's happening?"

The first that came up to me are:

> - What's going on?
> - What's up?

I am learning English, I am in a small country in Europe. I am looking for other ways to say it:

- Uncommon ways
- Funny and/or playing with words or double meanings
- Used in the past
- Very new, used in streets or only among very young people
- Common in a zone. For instance, only used in the Boston area

Comment: How goes it? What's doing? Whassup?

Comment: Here's a new one I learnt recently "What's up, dog?" It's American English.

Comment: Note that in Australia and I think UK, "what's up" is only used as an inquiry about something unusual, while in US it is more of a general inquiry. BTW "What's up, dog" sounds as though it is derived from BugsBunny's "What's up, Doc".

Comment: @Peter that's what I suspected too, but "What's up, dog" is used as a friendly greeting between guys. When I learned what was being said,  I then heard [it](https://tvquot.es/the-office/the-secret/) used in three or four episodes on the TV series "The Office" with Steve Carell.

Comment: What's happening? What's new? What's popping? 'Sup?

Answer (score 1):

- What gives?
- Penny for your thoughts?
- [What's the craic?](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Craic) (Ireland)

It's interesting with respect to @Reagan's answer that "craic" is also pronounced and sometimes written "crack".

Answer (score 1):

- [Wagwan](https://www.dictionary.com/e/slang/wagwan/) (Jamaican/Londoner)
- Shalom (Jewish/NYC/etc.)
- What’s cooking, good looking?
- [Sup?](https://www.dictionary.com/browse/sup)
- Kia Ora (New Zealand)
- G'day mate (Australia)
- [Whazzzuuuuup](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=NsJLhRGPv-M) (yes you have to drag it out)
- What’s with the face? (if someone looks angry or sad)
- Greetings earthling (funny/nerdy)

Note that "What's doing" (suggested by @Lambie) is NOT grammatical.

Answer (score 0):

I’ve started using "*What’s cracka lacking*"? I think I saw it on the internet and thought it was funny so now I use it. I’m pretty sure only high schoolers and other people around that age use this saying.

Comment: It sounds kinda dated, actually. I can imagine a Gen X-er saying it, but not a zoomer sincerely saying it. (I'm on the young end of millenials)